# Submit a form using Javascript with input named submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I have a HTML form where one of the inputs is called named `submit`
I also have a nicely formatted HTML element inside the form which is supposed to submit the form on click.

I noticed that form.submit is overridden by the input field which is named `submit` so I can't call `form.submit()` anymore.

I've searched for an answer, the general response is to rename the input. However I cannot do that. `submit` most appear as a parameter with a value in the request body.

Example code:

```
<form action="http://example.com/search" method="POST">
    <!-- other generated parameters -->
    <input value="findItems" name="submit" type="hidden">
    <a onclick="event.stopPropagation();this.parentNode.submit()" href="javascript:{}">
        <!-- this is dinamically generated 
            and generally much more complex --->
        <strong>search</strong> 
    </a>
</form>
```

Keep in mind that my constraints are the following:

- the element which the users clicks to submit the form is contains other *formatted* elements
- `submit` is a **required** parameter in the request body
- the request method must be **POST**
- cannot make any modifications to the back-end

PS: this is my first question on stack overflow, love this site.

Comment: Just a side note, you don't have an input with an attribute called submit, but with the name submit ;)

Comment: Please checkout the updated version of my answer.

Comment: @vbo Please read the "Background" regarded in the question that you meant carefully to know that the two questions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping submit as a parameter by the following:

```
<input value="findItems" name="submit[]" type="hidden" />
```

Just add the square brackets `[]` to the attribute name and you will be able to get it on the server-side.

## Updated:

### Or

You can supply your form with `<input type="submit">` and then triggering click event on it as follows:

```
<form action="http://google.com/search" method="POST">
    <!-- other generated parameters -->
    <input value="findItems" name="submit" type="hidden" />
    <a onclick="event.stopPropagation();" href="javascript:goo()">
        <!-- this is dinamically generated 
            and generally much more complex --->
        <strong>search</strong> 
    </a>
  <input type="submit" id="send" />
</form>
```

In the above code, we added input type of submit and assigned it to id `send` to allow accessing it from the DOM easily.

Also we added a function call `goo()` to the `href` of your `search` link. Now we will define that function and another function to trigger the event:

```
function goo(){     
       fireEvent(document.getElementById('send'),'click');
    }
    function fireEvent(obj, evt){
     var fireOnThis = obj;
     if( document.createEvent ) {
       var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
       evObj.initEvent( evt, true, false );
       fireOnThis.dispatchEvent( evObj );
     }
      else if( document.createEventObject ) { //IE
       var evObj = document.createEventObject();
       fireOnThis.fireEvent( 'on' + evt, evObj );
     } 
}
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/vecebo/1/

The submit button may be hide using CSS `style="visibility: hidden"`

The function of triggering the event is referenced from **[HERE](http://www.cristinawithout.com/content/function-trigger-events-javascript)**

Comment: adding [] seems like a weird hack, however your second solution look promising, I'll test it soon :)

Comment: it works! thank you, the best solution is to create a hidden submit button and to trigger the click event of the submit button

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

assuming there is only one form on the document,
or if that doesn't work, you can try calling the click method on the button

```
form.submit.click();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Unfortunately I have a variable number of forms, usually between 0 and 200 so I'll need to find then one I want to submit. `form.submit.click()` however seems like a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little something that might be of help. Since we clearly are unable to use the `form.submit()`, we can submit your form details using a synchronous AJAX call.

The jQuery code to tell you what I'm talking about:

```
<script>
function submitForm(){      
  $.ajax({
     url:  "http://example.com/search",
     data: {
         submit : $("#submit").val()
     },
     success: function(){alert("It worked!");},
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown)},
     async: false
  });
}
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="submit" name="submit"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:submitForm()">
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify this, I'm submitting the form to another domain. As far as I know AJAX does not allow this plus I also want to navigate to that site, not to process the response using Javascript.