# how to submit an input field made with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking how to submit submit an input field made with JavaScript.

I want to submit the value of the input fields made with JavaScript with the POST method to a file called "home.php". But I didn't find any possible way to do that, I hope someone helps me. I've included the full source code. I'll be really thankful for any help.

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <base target="_parent">
    <script>
        if (window.parent !== window) {
            try {
                window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ = window.parent.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;
            } catch (error) {
                // The above line can throw if we do not have access to the parent frame -- i.e. cross origin
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>Storybook</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="error-display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/2560291117/preview-0c18dfe69fe4ef4a04bd-bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the script that creates the field?

Comment: The same way you submit input fields from the static HTML. Either by submitting the form or using AJAX.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Barmar , Can you please help me , i tried to add <form action="home.php" method="POST"> and a submit bouton but when submitting the form the values of the input fields don't get submited

Comment: Show your code that adds the input fields.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/medipass/react-credit-card-input/master/docs/static/preview.0c18dfe69fe4ef4a04bd.bundle.js"></script>

it's this JS script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit a form using Javascript with input named submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504207/submit-a-form-using-javascript-with-input-named-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing up with POST or GET requests you can just use the built-in `document.querySelector('#YourIdHere)`
The # sign is important as it means that it's an id.
Also, you can add a submit button and fetch the website using the:

```js
fetch('urlHere', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data)
)
```

Is that good?
With input fields it looks something like that:

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <input id='input' type="text" value="">
   <button onclick="submit()">Submit!</button>
   <p id="title">Your text here!</p>
   <script>
     function submit() {
      const query = document.querySelector('#input').value;
      const title = document.getElementById('title');
      console.log(query);
      console.log(title.innerHTML = query);
     }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And using requests:

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <button onclick="submit()">Submit!</button>
   <script>
    function submit() {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'json';
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
       };
      };
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      xhr.send();

};
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getQueryById()` or `getElementById()` / `querySelector()`?

Comment: My fault, fixed it

Comment: can you please add it to the source code , i'm new to JS , i didn't really understand  but if it works that's what i need , Thanks so much btw

Comment: please  please help me

Comment: What's the source code? I see no input fields over there...

Comment: How's that? Do you need to get data from an external website?